# imagecreatefromjpeg function not working in firefox

Tags: php, firefox, imagecreatefrompng

I am using gd library functions in an app and saving the created image using imagecreatefromjpeg. Strangely, everything is working fine in Chrome, but the image is not getting saved when using the app in firefox.

Can any body givne any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: PHP runs on the server, not the browser, so whatever is going wrong, it is in the supply of the image to the browser.  Perhaps you are not sending the right header.

Comment: Any code sample? What does mean its not getting saved (corrupted output etc.)?

Comment: php is server side, so the browser doesn't matter. But you should post some code..

Answer (score 0):

Try to Clear Cache of your Browser to get updated result. PHP is server side and not client side.